# Problem with sp_Updatestats

Tags: sql-server, statistics

I am having a problem when running sp_updatestats on my database it generates an error when my emp table is updating and disconnects I will paste the error here

```
Updating [dbo].[emp]
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

Is it because any problem with the table when I run DBCC checktable(emp) , it doesn't showed any problems.Then what will be the cause

**Update:**
How can we find the root cause of the problem without installing a service pack as mentioned by @gbn ,how can we eliminate it. what if the problem is occurring in version having sp2 installed ,If it  happens in a production server and installing service pack is the only way to resolve it ,as a dba what we can do?

Comment: What version are you running (SELECT @@VERSION)? IIRC there are some hotfixes for errors like this

Comment: @gbn Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)   Apr  2 2010 15:53:02   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Evaluation Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 5):

You are running RTM (10.50.1600.1): the latest patch is SP2 + CU3 (10.50.4266)

These include patches like [KB 2498786](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2498796)

Comment: ,but i didn't configured the peer to peer replication ,I just created a new database and created a new table ,and showing this error on running updatestats

Answer (score 1):

Instead of issuing a general sp_udpatestats try using the command

```
UPDATE STATISTICS [your_database_name].[schema_owner].[EMP]
```

You should then have detailed information for your EMP table.